# Kegg in Cytoscape: how to get plots with reaction IDs in place of EC numbers using KeggScape?

Tags: bioinformatics, biotechnology

I found a KeggScape manual page representing Kegg reactions in Reaction ID format, but I couldn't find how to get a Kegg plot with reaction IDs in place of EC numbers. Does anyone know?

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. I think you will need to provide more information if you hope for an answer. I do not use Cytoscape, but believe it is a general networking tool that has nothing intrinsically to do with Kegg. I see there is something called Keggscape. If that is what your question is about, you should edit it to say so, and provide a link to the documentation. Your title doesn't indicate you are talking about Cytoscape so I have edited it for you, putting your old title as a first line. If this is not correct, modify it.